# Play in rear wheel hub

Tags: hub

I've got some play in the rear wheel hub, which makes the wheel move sideways a bit. Here's a video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EpXNE9YYdzwxotgWbCeWi2DM9FOlmY7A

How can I fix this? Do I have to disassemble the hub?

Comment: How handy are you with tools?

Comment: @Criggie I can do the basic stuff: change tires/tubes, adjust derailers and v-brakes. Even changed a shift cable once with only minor damage (no indication of the current gear anymore). But I was hoping this could be adjusted without taking it all apart. In particular, I don't have the tool for removing the freewheel (Shimano MF TZ20). I also don't have the fancy spanners for the cones, only regular ones.

Comment: Consider this an opportunity to try something a little bit harder.  Yes you need to buy/borrow some tools  (cassette lockring remover, chain whip, and a right-size cone spanner, and some grease and rags)   but they're not too expensive.  And then you'll own them for life.

Comment: If this feels a bit beyond you, look around your area for a bike cooperative who will have the tools and can help you do your own work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hub looks like a serviceable cup and cone types, so you will be able to fix the problem.

You will have to disassemble the hub, but it is not a difficult procedure. You will need some special tools - a chain whip and cassette lock ring tool to get the cassette off, and possibly a cone wrench.

There are many resources available online that can guide you such as this [Park Tool Company article](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hub-overhaul-and-adjustment).

You may need to simply adjust the bearings, but you should check the amount of  wear on each bearing component and replace if necessary.

Comment: I'm accepting this, but in my case, it was not even necessary to remove the wheel. It was enough to hold the 17 mm nuts on the opposite sides of the hub and tighten. I eventually removed the axle to add some grease, but I was unable to remove the freewheel with an adjustable wrench (maybe with a long breaker bar it can come off).